# How can i use an already made vector in a Map?

Tags: java

im trying to make a PhoneBook in java.
i hard-coded a Vector of type Person `Vector<Person>`.
and added pesons to it.
now i have a `Phonebook Class` and inside of it as a field. I got a
 `Map<Character, Vector<Person>> mp = new TreeMap<>();`.
i got method that accept a character. and it should print all the persons that their name starts with the char from the hard-coded vector.
how can i make the hard-coded `Vector`, the value of the `Map`?

my phoneBook:

```
private Map<Character, Vector<Person> > phoneBook = new TreeMap<>();


public Vector<Person> getListPeople(Character character){

    Vector<Person> vecPerson = phoneBook.values().iterator().next(); // should bring back the vector i want to use
    System.out.println(vecPerson);
    Iterator<Person> persons = vecPerson.iterator();
    while(persons.hasNext()){
        Person temp = persons.next();
        if(temp.getName().startsWith("" + character)){
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
    return vecPerson;
}

public String getIndividualNumber(String name){
    Character myChar = name.charAt(0);
     Vector<Person> personas = (Vector<Person>) getListPeople(myChar);
     Iterator<Person> myItr = personas.iterator();
     while (myItr.hasNext()){
         Person temp = myItr.next();
         if(temp.getName().equals(name)){
             return temp.toString();
         }
     }
     return null;
}
```

Comment: Maps don't just have values, but key-value pairs. What key is your Vector supposed to have? Why did you decide to use a Map at all? What is the maps Key and Value supposed to represent in your Phonebook?

Comment: i decided to use map because it is homeowork of my teacher. so you telling me to make a phonebook i need maps that their keys are a-z Char and values are vectors with persons which starts with a-z?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do something like this:

```
Vector<Person> v;
Map<Character, Person> dictionary= new TreeMap<>();
v.forEach(it -> dictionary.put(it.name.charAt(0), it));
```